# What is the cause for classpath mismatch between compile-time and run-time in a multi-threaded application?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, classpath

I am writing a Swing desktop application. I compile my program using:

> C:\MyJavaPrograms\src>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\javac"  SVNTool.java -cp ".;C:\parsers\commons\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\parsers\svnkit-1.7.4-v1\lib\svnkit-cli-1.7.4-v1.jar;C:\parsers\svnkit-1.7.4-v1\lib\svnkit-1.7.4-v1.jar"

and I invoke my program using:

> C:\MyJavaPrograms\src>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\java"  SVNTool -cp ".;C:\parsers\commons\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\parsers\svnkit-1.7.4-v1\lib\svnkit-cli-1.7.4-v1.jar;C:\parsers\svnkit-1.7.4-v1\lib\svnkit-1.7.4-v1.jar"

It compiles fine. It starts fine.  But when I click on the button, it creates a SwingWorker thread, but this thread failed with NoClassDefFoundError.

I've searched the net, and been able to get around the problem by adding some jar files to the CLASSPATH environment variable using:

> C:\MyJavaPrograms\src>set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\parsers\svnkit-1.7.4-v1\lib\svnkit-1.7.4-v1.jar;C:\parsers\svnkit-1.7.4-v1\lib\svnkit-cli-1.7.4-v1.jar;C:\parsers\commons\commons-lang-2.4.jar

So, what causes the classpath mismatch between compile-time and run-time in a multi-threaded Swing application? Is there a way to make all environment variables and command-line options available to threads?

Comment: Consider to use Maven to manage your dependencies.

Answer (score 8):

Threads have nothing to do with your problem. Suppose you use a class `Foo` from library `A.jar` in your source file. To compile your class, you need `A.jar` in the classpath, for the compiler to be able to know about `Foo`, its methods, fields, etc. But if the code of `Foo` relies on another class `Bar` which is in `B.jar`, you will also need `B.jar` in the runtime classpath.

In short, you only need the direct dependencies in the classpath to compile. But you need all the transitive dependencies in the classpath to run the program.

You should not mess with the CLASSPATH environment variable. Always use the -cp option to set the classpath of your program.

Comment: We have massive classpaths in our large web-app.   Putting it on the command line is not an option because it makes `ps` unreadable.  In those cases we always use the `CLASSPATH` env variable in our start scripts.

Comment: If it's an environment variable that stays local to a given script, it's of course acceptable. What I meant was to avoid using a global CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: In my case, Foo and Bar both exist in the same jar, and I specify the same value for the -cp option.  I still do not see why it is failing with NoClassDefFoundError.  Is there a way to make all environment variables and command-line options available to threads?

Comment: We can't know either because you didn't said what the exception stack trace was, and what the CLASSPATH contains. All the threads in a JVM have access to the same runtime classpath and the same environment variables. Your problem has nothing to do with threads. The fact that the error happens inside a SwingWorker just means that the SwingWorker is the first to load the class which is missing in the classpath.